# can we use "which" after troops?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

which of the following is correct?

1. Rome was threatened by Hunnish troops who showed their superiority ......
2. Rome was threatened by Huniish troops which showed their superiority .....

Is *troops* a collective noun and can we treat collective nouns like objects?

Thank you.

Comment: The use of "which" in that context is ambiguous.

Comment: Does M-W say give different senses for 'troop' (and 'troops')? // I'd say that the default sense of 'troops' has to be the synonym of 'soldiers' rather than the quasi-synonym of 'platoons'. This makes the default reading with 'which': 'Rome was threatened by Hunnish troops, which occurrence showed their superiority ....'

Comment: Neither is correct and, no, "troops" is not a collective noun. The mistake is that the relative clause should be a non-defining one, the kind separated by a comma. Even then, since the antecedent denotes human beings, the pronoun should be "who".